# What is MacUpdaterSwift in my com.apple.loginitems.plist file?

Tags: login-items

I saw some strange entries in my Login Items, so I decided to do some digging in the associated `com.apple.loginitems.plist` file, and found something called `MacUpdaterSwift`. Google only gave me three search results, and none of them made sense. What is this? Is it maybe malware?

Answer (score 2):

After decoding the LSSharedFileList entry, I discovered this is from an Erlang install.